# Site is scrolling down automatically aftear search

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

This is my site URL which is developed in magento(www.theprinterdepo.com), when a user searches, the page automatically scrolls down to the bottom. I have no idea if this due to any php code, jquery or javascript but I need help to detect and fix this.

I would paste code here, but I don't know what's responsible for this behaviour.

I thought it was IE problem, but its also reflects in Google Chrome.

thanks

Comment: Does your URL contain a `#` ?

Comment: What's with the _x=-1445&y=-10_ params in the URL?

Comment: no idea, this is a magento out of the box installation with a custom theme.

Comment: I just checked if I remove those querystring parameters, it makes no difference

Comment: Browser behavior = JavaScript. Need a link to see this behavior.

Comment: http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=t630

Comment: Did you duplicate this issue on other computers, browsers? So that we can be sure its not a faulty hardware (mouse).

Comment: There is a javascript onload being called for element ea, Try to comment that out and see if it helps.

Comment: Has one of the answers solved your question?  I can't reproduce the issue anymore.  If so, please accept their answer and if you feel like it, award the bounty that you've set to that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function()
{
var deftxt='Test';
var def=document.getElementById('ea');
def.onfocus = function()
{
this.value=(this.value==deftxt)?'':this.value;
}
def.onblur= function()
{
if(this.value=='')
{
this.value=deftxt;
}
else 
this.value;
}
***def.focus();***
def.blur();
}</script>
```

Here the textbox having id "**ea**" is set focus on. Please remove "**def.focus();**". Your issue will be solved.

Comment: can you please tell me in which JS file did you see this?

Comment: @LuisValencia it's not in a JS file, it's in the html, so it'd be in a phtml file. Impossible to tell you which one without access to the file. Search the string with an IDE or grep it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `def.focus()` from your script tag in the footer.

Comment: in which js file you found this?

Comment: this is a `<script>` tag in your html template

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps unrelated - but unless I am mistaken -  you have an accidental closure/circular reference. When you reference a JS object that contains a reference to a DOM object, which in turn references the JS object - you have a closure that creates a circular reference. In this case def.onBlur() / def.blur() is the culprit. (See the code below - a textbook example of a circular reference.) Not sure if this is causing your issue, but this is definitely something I would look into.

```
       <script>
        myFunction(){
        var elObj = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        elObj.onclick= function() {
        alert('This function is leaking.');
        }}
        myFunction();
       </script>
```